# Is there a way to define the recovery partition size used during Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recovery-partition

I want to reinstall Windows 10 and right away avoid the current 0x80070643 update error caused by the insufficiently sized recovery partition. But there seems to be no obvious way to define its size because it just appears out of thin air after installation. Is there some hidden option or maybe something I can modify on the installation media?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22h2#3231msgdesc) are the instructions to modify the partition size of the WinRE partition.  Reinstalling Windows WILL NOT solve this problem, as the default size (522MB) of the WinRE partition, will remain smaller than the update that resolves the BitLocker security vulnerability requires (250MB)

Comment: I am in a similar position with the OP and the point isn't just solving the problem on current installations (which can be done by resizing), but also avoiding it in future installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is apparently no convenient way to tell the installer a desired size, it's in hindsight obviously possible to just do it manually using the command prompt during the installation.

It's basically [Microsoft's instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5028997-instructions-to-manually-resize-your-partition-to-install-the-winre-update-400faa27-9343-461c-ada9-24c8229763bf) but without the REAgentC commands and no need to shrink and delete a partition.

For completeness sake:

- During drive management stop after the primary partition intended for Windows
- Enter the command prompt (`Shift` + `F10`)
- Run `diskpart` and

  - `select disk <index>`
  - `create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac size=<desired megabytes>`
  - `gpt attributes =0x8000000000000001`
  - `format quick fs=ntfs`
  - `exit`
- Close the command prompt
- Click the refresh button
- Create further partitions

If only a single partition is desired just leave some unallocated space in the desired recovery partition size and omit the `size` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows installation has no interface for selecting the
size of the recovery partition.

In almost all cases, when a Windows Update requires more space
than is available in the partition, Windows will create
automatically a new and larger recovery partition
(leaving the old one dangling).
You're not supposed to get this error during a
normal Windows installation.

It's quite easy to
[resize the recovery partition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5028997-instructions-to-manually-resize-your-partition-to-install-the-winre-update-400faa27-9343-461c-ada9-24c8229763bf),
so this problem can easily be solved when it arrives.

However, the recovery partition is quite small and normally
shouldn't present a problem. Windows will the reduce the size
of the Windows partition by the required amount automatically.

You should give us more information about the layout
of the disk, so we can understand why allocating space
for the recovery partition doesn't work in your case.
A screenshot of the entire screen of Disk Management would
be helpful.