# KB5034441 update error 80070643 - Increasing recovery partition size in VMWare

Tags: partitioning, windows-11, windows-update

I have two VMWare workstation virtual machines where update [KB5034441](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5034441-windows-recovery-environment-update-for-windows-10-version-21h2-and-22h2-january-9-2024-62c04204-aaa5-4fee-a02a-2fdea17075a8) update fails with error 0070643.
This supposedly is a too small recovery partition. Quoting from:

[KB5028997: Instructions to manually resize your partition to install the WinRE update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5028997-instructions-to-manually-resize-your-partition-to-install-the-winre-update-400faa27-9343-461c-ada9-24c8229763bf)

> Microsoft has changed how it updates PCs that run the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE). WinRE will be updated using the monthly cumulative update. This change only applies to PCs that get updates from Windows Update (WU) and Windows Server Update Services (WSUS). This change starts on June 27, 2023, for the Windows 11, version 22H2 cumulative update.

> Some PCs might not have a recovery partition that is large enough to complete this update. Because of this, the update for WinRE might fail. You will receive the error message, "Windows Recovery Environment servicing failed.” To help you recover from this failure, this article provides instructions to manually resize your recovery partition if you get a system ErrorPhase of 2. This requires your device to have the recovery partition after the OS partition. Use the steps below to verify this.

That same article contains the procedure for resizing the OS partition, deleting the old WinRE partition and creating a new one.

My `reagentc /info` output:

```
Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

Windows RE status:         Enabled
Windows RE location:       \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE
Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 80afc8c3-bead-11ee-b2c1-000c29a0c528
Recovery image location:
Recovery image index:      0
Custom image location:
Custom image index:        0
```

This tells me that the WinRE partition is disk 0 partition 1.

For disk 0, diskpart lists this:

```
Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    Recovery           499 MB  1024 KB
Partition 2    System              99 MB   500 MB
Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   599 MB
Partition 4    Primary             99 GB   615 MB
```

Indeed, recovery is partition 1.

Question:

This partition is 499 MB, yet the shrink operation for the System partition (to allow creation of a new recovery partition behind it) tells me that 250 should be enough ([numbers are megabytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/shrink-a-basic-volume)):

```
shrink desired=250 minimum=250
```

Question: **If I have 499 MB for the WinRE partition, how can this be too small?**
I suspect that something else may be going on, maybe because I'm running in a VM?
I'm reluctant to start meddling with partitions....

Comment: 500 MB seems too small now. I had a Windows 10 VM and would up making a new Windows 10 VM and that came out with 2 partitions:   UEFI and DATA,  and then a reference on Drive C Root for WinRE and updates now all work fine. This is all I can suggest to you.

Comment: [The current recommended size for WinRE > than 250MB](https://superuser.com/questions/1827605/). The BitLocker vulnerability patch itself requires the WinRE partition to have 250MB of free space. If the pre-update default size is smaller than the new default size that conditions can never be achieved. “This update requires 250 MB of free space in the recovery partition to install successfully.” - The correct size is 525MB. If you are worried create a snapshot of the VM. You are misreading the recommendation. You will shrink the system partition by 250MB then expand the WinRE partition by 250MB

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, 250 MB *free space*. OK. One question remains then: if this procedure deletes the old WinRE partition in front of my system partition, then recreates a new WinRE partition behind it ("*This requires your device to have the recovery partition after the OS partition*"), how can that be large enough? Or am I misreading this also, and does it mean that my VM image does not meet the requirements to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Please be very careful. This particular update is known to brick windows installations with the fix Microsoft provided.

There are plenty of YouTube videos specifically about this KB.

The basic advise for this KB is to ignore it. The fixes it does are not worth the trouble. Just keep letting it fail to install until Microsoft stops giving you the update, or it installs succesfully by itself.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kb5034441 most videos will say the same as this answer. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ArhwRe2jb8.
Latest status is that supposedly Microsoft has released a fix for KB5034441 and it should now install without any modifications. Basically the suggested solution is to just let it fail until Microsoft either retracts the update or releases a new one that takes its place.

Comment: @LPChip - If a fix has been released then Microsoft has released an update to the known issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22H2#3231msgdesc).

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, but I don't trust the page that gives instructions that have bricked many windows installs.

Comment: I'm unimpressed with that sample video. It's just mentioning that the update may fail and then adding lots of opinions. Definitely no proof of your statement "This particular update is known to brick windows installations with the fix Microsoft provided". Of course meddling with diskpart is a bit much to ask from users, and riskier than just running updates.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/192uqku/beware_kb5034441_as_part_of_jan_2024_updates/

Answer (score -1):

How are you installing this update? I have stretched the partition to 5GB and it still fails. Some advice suggests shrinking the partition to 250MB, still further advice suggests that this partition must follow the system partition (not necessarily the boot partition), but do not say if this means physically after, even directly after, or later in the enumeration. I understand it also fails if there is no recovery partition. There is no guidance as to the impact of Windows being in a primary partition and the recovery being in a secondary partition under MBR.

All in all a mess, but a stand alone install or a nuke from orbit install may get you where you need to be.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment, it will probably be removed (make it a comment under the question to preserve it). No, I have not installed the update and decided to wait for MS. To answer you: read the Reddit thread under LPChips answer; some people suggest 2 GB, others report a bricked box ;-(  But you already tried 5GB so... Yes, I'm also in doubt about what "must follow the system partition" means

Answer (score -1):

How 499MB can be too small? The recovery partition holds a file called Winre.wim. The size of that file will vary depending on windows version and if there are any drivers embedded in that file. I have seen sizes ranging from 430 to 590MB. Therefore a 499MB partition may not be enough. This is why Microsoft instructs to increase the recovery partition **by** 250MB (not to 250MB).

KB5028997 mentions: "this article provides instructions to manually resize your recovery partition if you get a system ErrorPhase of 2. This requires your device to have the recovery partition after the OS partition."

It seems your recovery partition is the first partition and so the article might not apply to you. For the use case described in the KB, the process will result in the new recovery partition to be larger by 250MB than before, rather than to be at 250MB. So if it was 500MB before, it will now be 750MB and should be enough to hold the recovery partition for the foreseeable future.

To see the wim file you can issue the command `reagentc /disable` which should cause the Winre.wim file to move to `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery`. Mind that it is a hidden and system file. If that file doesn't move there when the command is issued you can try and get a clean Wimre.wim and ReAgent.xml files from the Windows install media and try with those. Run `reagentc /info` to see status and `reagentc /enable` to re-enable the recovery environment.

Comment: The partition has to be larger than 250MB.  The instructions actually have you expand the current size of the WinRE partition by 250MB.  If the current size is around 525MB, logic suggests, the new size must be at least 250MB larger than the default size of 525MB before the update.  However, this answer appears to be more of a comment or observation, than an actual answer to the question. I am not prepared to answer this question, due to the fact, I also agree performing manually is not the best course of action.